# XmlWriter.Create not creating object in stream

Tags: c#, serialization

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter xdw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
ser.WriteObject(xdw, obj);
```

Length of ms is 0

Why?

Comment: Have you written any data to the xmlwriter? Because from your example you havent yet which is why the length is 0 still

Comment: Try calling `xdw.Flush()` afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = "bugaga!";
        System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (XmlWriter xdw = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
        {
            ser.WriteObject(xdw, obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ms.Length);
    }
}
```

**[update]** or just do xdw.Flush(), as already noticed

Comment: Dont miss the using / Dispose for the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @Malmi, `MemoryStream` doesn't have any unmanaged resourced, so it doesn't really matter.